# Haskell error No instance for (Floating Int)

Tags: haskell

This code is to get the distance between 2 points but i got a problem!

**UPDATED by @EduardoLeon**

```
rango2 :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]] -> [Int]
rango2 a b list = if (verif [(list!!a!!0),(list!!a!!1),(list!!a!!2)] (b)) then [1]
              else [0]

verif :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
verif a b = if ((distance a b) > a!!2) then True
        else False

difference :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
difference xs ys = zipWith (-) xs ys

 dotProduct :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> a
 dotProduct xs ys = sum $ zipWith (*) xs ys

 distance :: Floating a => [a] -> [a] -> a
 distance xs ys = sqrt $ dotProduct zs zs
where
zs = difference xs ys
```

**EDITED: I cant change Int to Float, because im doing operations with lists and now
throw this error!**

```
Proyecto.hs:71:18:
No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of `distance'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Int)
In the first argument of `(>)', namely `(distance a b)'
In the expression: ((distance a b) > a !! 2)
In the expression:
  if ((distance a b) > a !! 2) then True else False
```

Comment: Change the type signature of `rango2 :: (Floating a, Ord a) => Int -> [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]` to make it work. Also changing question to a new form after it has been answered confuses the future readers.

Comment: Indentation matters in Haskell.

Comment: Why are you comparing the `distance a b` against `a!!2`? It seems a better idea to store that value separately, outside of the list.

Comment: Because i need to compare distance a b, with a!!2 that is a range, i need to verify if the distance is out of range or not.. But i see i need to **distance [a!!0,a!!1] [b!!0,b!!1]** because im working with list of 3 elements [x,x,x] or **distance (take 2 a) (take 2 b)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your concrete question: Unlike more conventional languages, Haskell does not automatically cast integers to floats. In fact, the very notion of casting does not exist in Haskell. You need to use the function `fromIntegral` to convert integers to other numeric types. You could try the following in ghci:

```
> let x = 5 :: Integer
> sqrt x

<interactive>:3:1:
    No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of `sqrt'
    In the expression: sqrt x
    In an equation for `it': it = sqrt x
> let y = fromIntegral x :: Double
> sqrt y
2.23606797749979
```

---

I would also like to make some other suggestions regarding your coding style:

- Decompose your functions into smaller functions that do exactly one thing and do it well.
- The function `(!!)` traverses a linked list to find the `n`-th element. This is an `O(n)` operation, which is more expensive than necessary if you intend to retrieve multiple elements from the same list. Prefer solutions that avoid traversing the same list more than once.

Here is how I would find the distance between two points:

```
difference :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
difference xs ys = zipWith (-) xs ys

dotProduct :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> a
dotProduct xs ys = sum $ zipWith (*) xs ys

distance :: Floating a => [a] -> [a] -> a
distance xs ys = sqrt $ dotProduct zs zs
  where
    zs = difference xs ys
```

Answer (score 3):

> I was searching and i saw that i need to change Int to Float?

Just change the type signature to `Float` and things will start working:

```
verif :: [Float] -> [Float] -> Bool
```

You  need to change the type signature of your code to indicate that it works with floating data since `sqrt` function operates on that. A more generic solution would be this:

```
verif :: (Floating a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
verif a b = if (sqrt((((b!!0)-(a!!0))*((b!!0)-(a!!0)))+(((b!!1)-(a!!1))*((b!!1)-(a!!1)))) < a!!3)
            then True
            else if (sqrt((((b!!0)-(a!!0))*((b!!0)-(a!!0)))+(((b!!1)-(a!!1))*((b!!1)-(a!!1)))) == a!!3)
                 then True
                 else False
```

The use of the `!!` function isn't encouraged in Haskell. I would suggest you to rewrite the function in a more functional way.

Comment: `Float` is single precision, usually you want `Double` instead. (A bit of unfortunate naming inherited from C and the like, I guess.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you revisit your design. What are the meanings of the lists `a` and `b` in `verif`? It looks like you are finding the distance between two points. You can create a type:

```
data Point = Point Double Double
```

and a function

```
distance :: Point -> Point -> Double
```

to make your code much more readable.

This should also eliminate doing the same calculation twice by using a `where` clause or `let` binding.